# How to display a div when 3 Radiobuttons from 3 questions checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display 2 different div when the user answer 3 questions. 
All questions have Yes and No answers which is shown by radio buttons.
I want to show div2 when 3 NO are given by the users. If ONLY ONE of the answers is Yes then the div1 must be shown.

this is the code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function display(e){ 
            if(e.value == "yes"){ 
    document.getElementById("hidediv1").style.display='block'; 
                document.getElementById("hidediv2").style.display='none';
   } 
            else if(e.value =="no"){ 
                document.getElementById("hidediv2").style.display='block'; 
                document.getElementById("hidediv1").style.display='none'; 
            } 
         }         
</script>
```

```html
<form id="stu01" action="#" method="post">
 <p>1. Q1?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sq01" value="yes" onclick="display(this)">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="sq01" value="no" onclick="display(this)">No
 </p>
 <p>2. Q2?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sq02" value="yes" onclick="display(this)">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="sq02" value="no" onclick="display(this)">No
 </p> 
 <p>3. Q3?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="sq03" value="yes" onclick="display(this)">Yes
  <input type="radio" name="sq03" value="no" onclick="display(this)">No
 </p>
 <div id="hidediv1" style="display:none">
    
 </div>
    
 <div id="hidediv2" style="display:none">
 
 </div>     
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that i understand ur request right..

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/x51z91oL/)**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var checkedNo = $('input[type="radio"]').filter(function () {
        return $(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() === "no";
    });
    if (checkedNo.length === 3) {
        $('#hidediv1').show();
        $('#hidediv2').hide();
    } else {
        $('#hidediv2').show();
        $('#hidediv1').hide();
    }
});
```

**Full version:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Form Radio Button</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="stu01" action="#" method="post">
   <p>1. Q1?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sq01" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="sq01" value="no">No
   </p>
   <p>2. Q2?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sq02" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="sq02" value="no">No
   </p> 
   <p>3. Q3?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sq03" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="sq03" value="no">No
   </p>
   <div id="hidediv1" style="display:none">
      No!
   </div>
      
   <div id="hidediv2" style="display:none">
         Yes!
   </div>     
  </form>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b‌​8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
       var checkedNo = $('input[type="radio"]').filter(function () {
           return $(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() === "no";
       });
       if (checkedNo.length === 3) {
           $('#hidediv1').show();
           $('#hidediv2').hide();
       } else {
           $('#hidediv2').show();
           $('#hidediv1').hide();
       }
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working properly in the demo panel, but its not working in my file! does it have any embedded code?!

Comment: Yeah its requiring `jQuery`

Comment: May I know which jQuery file did you use ?

Comment: `<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: I am still struggling to find it out.... Do you mind, if i ask you to do me a favor and send the file to me?!

Comment: The file what u looking for is here: [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js)

Comment: And confirm my answer as a right one for help in the future

Comment: Yea, your answer is working properly. I meant the html file. if you can do a favor and send the html file to me!

Comment: I edited my answer with full HTML version.. hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Use onChange event listener, update a variable status, check when it is 3, append your div